# How can i display specific gridview row data on a winform to another winforms combobox

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I am using a win form to search the record and when the record is selected from a grid on celldoubleclick event. The search form should be closed and the selected row record is loaded back to to main form from which search form is begin called.

The code to open the search form.

```
private void F1Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Forms.frmSearchNewAccount frm = new Forms.frmSearchNewAccount();
        frm.ShowDialog();
        if (frm.DialogResult == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //here comes the selected record
        }
    }
```

//Search Form grid view cell double click event code is here

```
try
        {
            if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
            {
                this._SelectedRecord = new Flour_Mills.PARTY();
                _SelectedRecord.PARTY_ID = (string)((DataTable)SearchPartydataGrid.DataSource).Rows[e.RowIndex]["PARTY_ID"];
                _SelectedRecord.NAME = (string)((DataTable)SearchPartydataGrid.DataSource).Rows[e.RowIndex]["NAME"];
                Controller.PartyDAL.Load(_SelectedRecord.PARTY_ID);
                DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
                this.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

The _selectedRecord is a static variable but it is not accessible in main form.

Any Suugestions????
If u need more explination I am here to to elaborate more.

Answer (score 0):

Simply it can be do as:

```
public var _selectedRecordFromSearchForm;

private void F1Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Forms.frmSearchNewAccount frm = new Forms.frmSearchNewAccount();
    frm.ShowDialog(this); // pass this form as Owner
    if (frm.DialogResult == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        //here comes the selected record
    }
}
```

In search form:

```
this._SelectedRecord = new Flour_Mills.PARTY();
_SelectedRecord.PARTY_ID = (string)((DataTable)SearchPartydataGrid.DataSource).Rows[e.RowIndex]["PARTY_ID"];
_SelectedRecord.NAME = (string)((DataTable)SearchPartydataGrid.DataSource).Rows[e.RowIndex]["NAME"];
Controller.PartyDAL.Load(_SelectedRecord.PARTY_ID);
this.Owner._selectedRecordFromSearchForm = _SelectedRecord;  // set _searchRecoed to owners field
DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
this.Close();
```

Comment: Hamlet, u wrote that set the _searchRecord to ownerfields. in this line 'this.Owner._selectedRecordFromSearchForm' after owner is there a variable name or some thing else????

Comment: @MuhammadShehzad It is variable (field) name which must be defined in caller form as shown in first line of first snippet of my post.

Answer (score 0):

You could declare `_SelectedRecord` as public in your search form and when the form closes you can access the variable like this :

```
  if (frm.DialogResult == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        var SelectedRecord = frm._SelectedRecord;
    }
```